# How can I get the application names from an npm install command using a RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
npm install lodash hapi thinky when
```

I have this regex:

```
npm install ([\w\.\-]+)@?([0-9_\.\-\^]*)
```

But it only returns the first app name `lodash`. Which regex can I use to get `lodash, hapi, thinky, when` as a result?

Comment: `npm install (?:([\w\.\-]+)@?([0-9_\.\-\^]*)\s*)*` https://regexr.com/40poj

Comment: Return all together or separated?

Comment: @Oram it only returns 'when'.

Comment: @Mohammad separated

Comment: `npm install (\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)`

Comment: @TheScientificMethod I don't know the number of groups that I have...

Comment: @Sheren You'll need to split it by `\s` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
npm install ((?:(?:[\w\.\-]+)@?(?:[0-9_\.\-\^]*)\s*)+)
```

This basically captures the whole thing after `npm install` into group 1. Then you can split this by `\s+`:

```js
var regex = /npm install ((?:(?:[\w\.\-]+)@?(?:[0-9_\.\-\^]*)\s*)+)/g;
var match = regex.exec("npm install lodash hapi thinky when");
var group1 = match[1];
console.log(group1.split(/\s+/));
```

Comment: I think using long pattern isn't necessary if you used `split()` after regex. Use `/npm install\s(.*)/`

Comment: @Mohammad But OP's first attempt suggests that he/she does want to match things like `npm install a&b` because of the `&`.

Comment: I used this regex which is similar to yours (I used from comments above)

npm install (?:\-.*? )?([\w\.\-]+)@?([0-9_\.\-\^]*)

Answer (score 0):

You can match `npm install` from the start of the string and then use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to capture in a group one or more times a word character.

`^npm install|(\w+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4VKor/1)

If you want to match more than a word character, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add the characters you want to match for example `([\w.-]+)`

```js
const regex = /^npm install|(\w+)/g;
const str = `npm install lodash hapi thinky when`;
let m;
let result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1]) {
    result.push(m[1]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex here. You can do something simple as this:

```js
const input = "npm install lodash hapi thinky when";
const output = input.slice(11).trim().split(/\s+/);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use Regex to get the things you need! Follow my method:

```js
var str="npm install lodash hapi thinky when";
var regex = /(?<=(npm install ([A-Za-z_ \.]*)))(\w+)(?=([A-Za-z_ \.]*))/g;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```